# Get wrongly classified samples from tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

When reading image data via

```
train = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  './data', 
  labels='inferred', 
  label_mode='binary', 
  validation_split=0.2, 
  subset="training", 
  image_size=(img_height, img_width), 
  batch_size=sz_batch, 
  crop_to_aspect_ratio=True
)
```

they are stored in a tensorflow dataset. I read in the validation data with the same routine. To analyze my NN (a sequential tensorflow NN) I want to plot the wrongly classified samples (pictures). I can easily get the predictions via

```
pred = model.predict(validation)
```

But how can I get the wrongly classified samples out of the tensorflow dataset?

Answer (score 0):

To get the wrongly classified samples you can use the code like below where 'classes' are the originial labels and 'pred_labels' are the predicted labels and their indices will be stored in the indices list

```
wrong_pred=[]
indices=[]
for i in range(len(classes)):
  if classes[i]!=pred_labels[i]:
    indices.append(i)
    wrong_pred.append([classes[i],pred_labels[i]])
```

Please find the complete code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/f55cc7746b33bbe36cfa24aa7f7b3def/untitled147.ipynb#scrollTo=mZ20CNvPLeWw). Thank you!